# Ubuntu 12.04 ruby bundle install error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ruby, deployment, rvm

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to my Ubuntu server.
I already installed `rvm` and right now I'm trying to use `bundler` in order to deploy my app.

However I'm getting this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /myroot/repos/myapp/.bundle (Errno::EACCES)
```

First, What user is executing the whole `rvm` commands?  I mean I have `rake`, `bundle` etc, in my path, but I don't know exactly which user is executing them.

As a first intent I tried changing the permissions for all the files inside `/myapp` folder. Giving them `root:rvm`, but no luck.

Now if I try to run the bundle command as `sudo` (or in fact any ruby command) I'm getting errors similar to this one:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper
```

So, a little explanation of what the wrapper is and why is it not finding ruby would help me a lot to understand this kind of error.

Comment: I'm gonna be extremely lazy and just recommend that you delete the changes that you've done so far and simply run https://github.com/vaneyckt/Ruby-on-Rails-installation-script/blob/master/install.sh as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to not use `sudo` for `rvm`, `ruby` and any RubyGems installed commands as `sudo` by default losses environment variables used to configure RVM / Ruby / RubyGems.

If you really need to use `sudo` - go with `rvmsudo` - but I need to warn you it elevates privileges exposing your system, it's a security risk.